# Maven site deploy logs filling with [WARNING] Required credentials to nexus 3

Tags: maven, nexus

maven deploy to Nexus is filling build logs with [WARNING] Required credentials not available for BASIC .

It doesn't seem to cause any issues but clouds the logs..

```
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.4:deploy (deploy) @ ingensg-int-test-ce-lite-bdd ---
http://10.123.45.67:8081/repository/site/com.my.proj/1.0-SNAPSHOT_07-Apr-2016-14-06/ - Session: Opened
[INFO] Pushing /opt/my-proj/target/site/masterthought
[INFO]    >>> to http://10.123.45.67:8081/repository/site/com.my.proj/1.0-SNAPSHOT_07-Apr-2016-14-06/./
[WARNING] Required credentials not available for BASIC <any realm>@10.123.45.67:8081
[WARNING] Preemptive authentication requested but no default credentials available
```

Full Nexus version Sonatype NexusOSS `3.0.0-b2016011501`

Comment: Issue raised on this: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10112

Comment: any news about this? how to fix it?